# Libgdx - play animation from object

Tags: object, 3d, libgdx, blender

I am developin a desktop/android application in Libgdx and I would like to import an animation I have done in Blender. I've exported the .obj file from Blender and successfully imported it in libgdx so now that I start the application I can see the model but it is not moving. What should I do so I can make it move according to the keyframes? Thank you in advance! This is my code:

```java
public void create () {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.50f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(20f, 20f, 20f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("mod1.obj", Model.class);
    loading = true;
   }

private void doneLoading() {        
    Model mod1_model = assets.get("mod1.obj", Model.class);
    ModelInstance mod1_instance= new ModelInstance(mod1_model);
    mod1_instance.transform.setToTranslation(10f, 0, -10f);
    instances.add(mod1_instance);

    loading = false;
}

@Override
public void render () {
    if (loading && assets.update())
        doneLoading();
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

Comment: Don't use .obj files (obj doesn't support animations). Instead use fbx-conv. See also: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/

Answer (score 2):

Use AnimationController of 3d package to control Animation

```
private AnimationController animation;
```

in create() or show() method:

```
//Note you can get animation information by Animation Description
animationDescription = new AnimationController(modelInstance);
//when you export from blender to fbx the animation name is "new take" but here I used 'Walk'
animation.animate("Walk", 2, 1f, null, 0.2f);
```

in render() method:

```
//Note Gdx graphic delta
animation.update(delta);
//then render your instance
```

Comment: "animation.animate("Walk", 2, 1f, null, 0.2f);" would that move the model according to these coordinates? The thing is that I've already created the animation in Blender so I just want to play it in libgdx. 

Otherwise I've converted the model to g3db and it is now showing on the screen but it is not moving. :?

Comment: animate() is for you action animation not moving whole character, like moving rotating or moving nodes which might be skinned, for moving character you should use transform, like modelInstance.transform.translate().

Comment: Also do not forget to update animation with delta in render()